# Pandas groupby: coordinates of current group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a data frame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':['A','A','B','B','C','C'],'score':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

At first, say, I want to compute the groups' sums of scores. I usually do

```
def group_func(x):
    d = {}
    d['sum_scores'] = x['score'].sum()
    return pd.Series(d)
df.groupby('group').apply(group_func).reset_index()
```

Now suppose I want to modify `group_func` but this modification requires that I know the group identity of the current input `x`. I tried `x['group']` and `x[group].iloc[0]` within the function's definition and neither worked.

> Is there a way for the function `group_func(x)` to know the defining coordinates of the current input `x`?

In this toy example, say, I just want to get:

```
pd.DataFrame({'group':['A','B','C'],'sum_scores':[3,7,11],'name_of_group':['A','B','C']})
```

where obviously the last column just repeats the first one. I'd like to know how to make this last column using a function like `group_func(x)`. Like: as `group_func` processes the `x` that corresponds to group 'A' and generates the value 3 for `sum_scores`, how do I extract the current identity 'A' within the local scope of `group_func`?

Comment: try `x.name` -- I think that should work

Comment: I haven't voted, but you should provide your desired output

Comment: I'm confused, you already have the group identifier in the resulting dataframe

Comment: @PaulH I know but I would like to access it within `group_func`. Say I want to look up something in another table and if I know which group the current `x` belongs to, I can use that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `.name`

```
def group_func(x):
        d = {}
        d['sum_scores'] = x['score'].sum()
        d['group_name'] = x.name # d['group_name'] = x['group'].iloc[0] 
        return pd.Series(d)
    
df.groupby('group').apply(group_func)
Out[63]: 
       sum_scores group_name
group                       
A               3          A
B               7          B
C              11          C
```

Your code fix see about marked line adding `''`